# How can I Get ADUser

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to get the AD user account via Powershell, I need to import the name from csv and retrieve their AD results.

The list is only stored with "Display Name"

test.csv

```
name
Peter Chan
John Wu
Tom Wong
```

PS script

```
 $list = Import-Csv '.\test.csv'

foreach ($i in $list) {
    Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq '$i.name'"
}
```

Error

```
Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: 'Name -eq @{name=Peter Chan}.name' Error Message: 'syntax error' at position: '10'.
At line:2 char:1
+ Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq $i.name"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADFilterParsingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Error parsing query: 'Name -eq @{name=Peter Chan}.name' Error Message: 'syntax error' at
   position: '10'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

When I run Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like 'Peter Chan'"  , I can get the result i want. It shows that it is a array type @{name=Peter Chan}.name, what should I need to change on the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables get expanded in strings not property expressions.

Change this:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq '$i.Name'"
```

TO

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -eq '$($i.Name)'"
```